# Default search result listing to categories only, no product to display

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, module, search, category-products

Hi i want to create a custom module for search functionality, where it should search only from the list of categories provided by its custom location attribute,
for example
i have a list of categories as under 
Root category: Restaurant

- cat1 {location: Delhi}
- cat2 {location: Delhi}
- cat3 {location: Bangalore}

or so on..

I want to search as Delhi, it should show results as:
cat1, cat2 only,,

and while clicking on cat1 or cat2 it should show all its products.

How can i achieve this?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `advanced search` already built in Magento. `http://www.yoursite.com/catalogsearch/advanced/`.

Follow this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/search_and_advanced_search/how_to_add_search_by_category_to_advanced_search) to integrate in your extension.

You will need to overwrite these blocks to get the result.

Comment: i followed that link previously, it is giving the list of product under that category, no the list of categories matching that search query. my objective is to list the categories, and while clicking on category link, It should display all its products.

Comment: I see, aren't you using `layered navigation`?

Comment: no, i'm not using it, even that one is also required, how could i enable that

Comment: It should be set `Category > Display Settings Tab > Is Anchor` to "Yes". This will enable layered navigation on your category & search result page. Where all related categories will be listed for that search.

Comment: Thanks it works, now i just need to add couple of attributes to category, overwrite each of its layout.